# jQuery .live()-functionality for other jQuery methods such as .text()

Tags: live, jquery

I have the problem that my jQuery stuff isn't working after a div which includes elements being manipulated by my jQuery code are reloaded by ajax. The jQuery .live function helped me out that at least all my events are triggered. However functions like .text() are still not working. E.g.

```
$('#idOfElementBeingInDivWhichIsReloadedByAjax').text('New text');
```

Has anybody suggestions how to cope with this issue?

Edit: The problem is that the web site I'm working on loads its page content with ajax when clicking on a navigation item. All the jQuery functionality works when the sites are visited for the first time. However at the second time the DOM is reloaded and jQuery still uses the original DOM, so methods like .text() don't show changes any more. As mentioned above the .live() method helped me that at least events are still triggered after the second call of a specific page.

Comment: need more context, could you please more code? At least the callback method of your ajax call

Comment: what is type of idOfElementBeingInDivWhichIsReloadedByAjax?

Comment: You can simply run that code in the ajax callback (not necessarily in the callback function itself of course) when appropriate. Only events need to be "live"... The implementation of `live` has nothing to do with tracking new elements as they are created, which is what you would need to do if you want other methods to be "live" like `.text`.

Comment: Guys - let him explain it in better way before you 'vote-down'

Comment: @Adil: this element could be a div or a span.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this, is to make sure that your code is executed after the ajax reload. A common approach is to create a init() function, which are called from the ajax callback function.

```
$(function(){
  $('#myParentAjaxDiv').load('somepage.html', function(){
    initStuff();
  });
});

function initStuff(){
  $('#idOfElementBeingInDivWhichIsReloadedByAjax').text('New text');
}
```